# Select (show) only different columns from almost similar rows

Tags: sql, select, db2

I have a table with many columns 50+. in order to take decisions I analyze any variant data. 

Actually my query: 
`SELECT maincol, count(maincol) FROM table where (conditions) group by maincol having count(maincol) > 1`

then:
`SELECT * FROM table where (conditions) and maincol = (previous result)`

 before consult displays all rows and I have to search one by one

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, manycolumns..., colN
5       7    1      13   341     9                    123
5       7    2      13   341     5                    123
```

I want to get:

```
col3,   col6
  1      9
  2      5
```

because it's difficult searching manually column by column.

- N columns could be different

- I don't have access to credentials, then I can't use a programing language to manage results.
- Working on DB2

Comment: You question could use some clarity. Are you attempting to find columns of data within a query result that do not follow a particular pattern?

Comment: Data is so different, want to find similar columns.

Comment: Offtopic: `count(1)` whats that? Is that still from the SQL optimizers dark days where `COUNT(1)` was faster then using `COUNT(*)` Ontopic: not sure if i follow you how you get the expected result or what you mean with it.or what you call "similar columns." as i don't see it.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, want to get different data from same column. i.e. col3: has 1 (first row) and 2 (second row). Then col3 is eligible column to show as result

Comment: @Vrian7 You must use some procedure logic for this. I.e. `insert select` into some temporary table with an additional "flag" column (`case when min(colN)=max(colN) then 0 else 1 end as colN_changed`) for each data column `colN`. Then you must process this temporary table and construct the final select on its data *dynamically*, including only those `colN`s with `colN_changed` flag == 1.

Comment: If it is only one time analysis, why not use a text editor with diff capability (e.g. vim -d)? How many rows do you expect in your result? (Your example has only two.)

Answer (score 0):

This will be a little tedious but worth it. This assumes that  col1 through coln are all of the same type. If not, cast each to character in the select clause.

The result set will identify the maincol values that occur more than once that also have one or more columns with differing values. The columns that differ will be named.

Select maincol, colname, count(distinct colvalue)
From (
Select maincol, ‘column1’ as colname, col1 as colvalue 
from table
Union 
Select maincol, ‘column2’ as colname, col2 as colvalue 
from table
Union 
Select maincol, ‘column3’ as colname, col3 as colvalue 
from table
Repeat this pattern for remaining columns
)
Group by maincol, colname
Having count(distinct colvalue) > 1

You could even join the result set from above with the original table to show the entire row including the name of the columns that differ:

Select b.colname, a.* 
From table a, Select(
include entire query from above
) as b
Where a.maincol = b.maincol